# linq2sql: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a linq2sql setup where objects are sent from client side (flex via flourinefx) and attach them to a new datacontext a seen below:

I also have a "global" datacontext that is used throughout the session.

```
    public static void Update(Enquiry enquiry)
    {
        OffertaDataContext db = new OffertaDataContext();


        db.Enquiries.Attach(enquiry);
        db.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, enquiry);

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

This approach usually works fine, but after a while I get the error "Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use".

Comment: This is possibly the least descriptive error that I've seen yet in LINQ. Ugh. SQL gives a better error in this case? Wow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this error happens if you `Attach` an *entity* to a `DataContext` that was already loaded.

The code that causes the error is exactly like you show here? After creating the new `OffertaDataContext` do you query anything before the `Attach`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'd fetched the old record from the database to check for some properties agains the new, and i used the same DataContext. I solved with two sepparate using clauses.

Answer (score 43):

I was getting this error and it was because I had forgotten to set the Primary Key field in the database to "Identity Specification" (auto-increment).  When I changed this I was good.  Doh!

Comment: What if you cannot modify the DB?

Answer (score 5):

This might not be your issue (I can't tell), but it was mine and as people google this it might help someone else.  If you aren't using the built-in Linq-to-SQL designer or SQLMetal stuff to generate your Linq-to-SQL classes, or if you forgot to make your ID column an IDENTITY, you may be missing a property on your column attribute called "IsDbGenerated". Be sure your column attribute looks something like this:

```
<Column(Name:="ID", DbType:="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", CanBeNull:=False, IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True)>
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you inserting several entities at once, may you are just trying to insert a duplicate entity into current datacontext. I know this is too simple, but it just happened to myself.

Comment: yup. I wish they'd just said "attempt to insert duplicate primary key"

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to add multiple new objects in one hit where the LinqEntities are being created with a key of 0?

I had this issue in the past when I was trying to add items into a table on my page and then when I tried to delete or update these items, multiples would have the key 0.  So obviously it didn't know what to do with my requests...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've been doing to get around this error. Basically you find where this row is in the database based on a primary key. If it doesn't exist then you insert it. Otherwise you get the version from the database and update all of the necessary fields.

```
public static void Update(Enquiry enquiry)
{
    JobsDataContext db = new JobsDataContext();

    var enquiries = from e in db.Enquiries
                    where e.PKID == enquiry.PKID
                    select e;

    if (enquiries.Count() < 1)
    {
        db.Enquiries.InsertOnSubmit(enquiry);
    }
    else
    {
        Enquiry updateEnquiry = enquiries.Single();

        updateEnquiry.LengthMm = enquiry.LengthMm;
        updateEnquiry.ShippedQty = enquiry.ShippedQty;
        updateEnquiry.StatusCode = enquiry.StatusCode;
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This can become tedious if you make updates to your database schema all the time, as you'll have to come back here to update the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after selecting a row from the database with the primary key of say 'BOB'.  Then i would truncate the table with `dc.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE ShippingReport");` and do `SubmitChanges()`, thinking this would get rid of the field and I'd be able to insert another with the same key, but I got the OP's error when trying to insert.  Just had to do `dc = new DataContext();` after the first SubmitChanges and that fixed it for me, since that object still existed in the DataContext, which is basically what bruno conde's answer says.

Answer (score 0):

try this even if your TEntity's (here Area) ID is an Identifier column;
Just it, without any change in your SP or Model:

```
public void InitForm()
{
    bnsEntity.DataSource = CacheManagement.cachedAreas;
    newID = CacheManagement.cachedAreas.LastOrDefault().areaID + 1;
    grdEntity.DataSource = bnsEntity;
}

private void tsbNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newArea = new Area();
    newArea.areaID = (byte)newID++;
    dataContext.GetTable<Area>().InsertOnSubmit(newArea);
    bnsEntity.Add(newArea);
    grdEntity.MoveToNewRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar aproach to Noah's, but I use a stored procedure to verify if a record with that PK exists or not, this way the Entity is not loaded in the context and the update code only involves two lines of code and will not require changes in the future when you add/remove fields from the table, it will require to change the SP only if the PK of the table changes:

```
bool existe = Convert.ToBoolean(dbc.spSConfigReportesPeriodicos(configReportesPeriodicos.CodigoCliente));

if (existe)
{
    dbc.ConfigReportesPeriodicos.Attach(configReportesPeriodicos);
    dbc.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, configReportesPeriodicos);
}
else
{
    dbc.ConfigReportesPeriodicos.InsertOnSubmit(configReportesPeriodicos);
}
dbc.SubmitChanges();
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spSConfigReportesPeriodicos
(
    @codigoCliente int
)
AS

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ConfigReportesPeriodicos WHERE CodigoCliente = @codigoCliente)
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0

RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do that kind of checking to see whether you need to use Updates or Inserts - that's for Linq to do!

Here's an example from a project I'm working on (sorry it's in VB.Net :) ) which demonstrates how to solve this.

The code is yet unoptimised and pretty ugly - but it gets the point across. You can ignore the bit where it pulls values from the checkboxlist - that just shows how you can update child entities.

Here's the OnUpdating method, which encompasses the update (this is truncated code):

```
Protected Sub LinqDataSource22_Updating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceUpdateEventArgs) Handles LinqDataSource22.Updating

            ' The main entity
            Dim updatedObject As FeedbackDraft = e.NewObject

            updatedObject.Modified = DateTime.Now
            updatedObject.ModifiedBy = UserHelper.GetCurrentUserName

            ' Example: Modify the updated object
            Dim aList As RadioButtonList = FeedbackFormView.FindControl("MyRadioButtonList")
            If aList IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(aList.SelectedValue) Then
                updatedObject.aProperty = aList.SelectedValue
            End If


            ' Main context - for updating parent entity
            Using ctx As New CustomDataContext()

                ' Example: ... more modification of the main entity
                updatedObject.Status = "Draft"

                ' Deal with child items
                ' Secondary context - for checking against existing data in DB and removing items that have been unselected in the form
                Using ctx2 As New CustomDataContext()

                    ' We need to pull the record from the database to get the full constructed object graph
                    ' This method does a linq query to retrieve the FeedbackDraft object by ID
                    Dim originalObject As FeedbackDraft = GetOriginalFeedbackDraft(ctx2, updatedObject.FeedbackId)

                    ' ... truncated ...

                    ' Loop through CheckBoxList items and updated our entity graph
                    For Each li As ListItem In cbList.Items

                        ' ... code to work with ListItem truncated ...

                        Dim c As New ChildObject()
                        updatedObject.ChildObjects.Add(c)
                        ' Set the child collection to insert - this is using the main context
                        ctx.ChildObjects.InsertOnSubmit(c)


                        ' We can also delete things using the secondary context
                        Dim o as OtherChildObject()
                        o = GetOtherChildObjectById(updatedObject.FeedbackId)
                        ctx2.OtherChildObjects.DeleteOnSubmit(o)
                        ctx2.SubmitChanges()

                    Next
                End Using

                ' You can do further child object updates here...

                ' Now, attach main object for update
                ctx.PartnerFeedbackDrafts.Attach(updatedObject, e.OriginalObject)
                ctx.SubmitChanges()

            End Using

            e.Cancel = True

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened in a situation where I had retrieved an entry, and then tried to update the entry with a new entry. Brainfart one might say, these things happens though. :p

```
public void UpdateEntry(Entity entity)
{
    var oldEntry = select ....
    var updatedEntity = new Entity{...}; // mix of entity and oldEntry

    _repository.Update<Entity>(updatedEntity);
}
```

Becomes

```
public void UpdateEntry(Entity entity)
{
    var oldEntry = select ....

    oldEntry.CreationDate = entity.CreationDate {...}

    _repository.Update<Entity>(oldEntry);
}
```